# Angular - $scope is not defined when calling functions from the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an existing application where I want to use some angular controlled parts.

I created an helper to bind dynamic HTML template to angular and it does the following:

```
AngularHelper.ShowModal = function (template, anchor, scopeProperties, controllerName) {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    var template = $.tmpl("InputPane/filterValuesSelectDialog");

    var $injector = angular.injector(["ng", "app"]);

    $injector.invoke(["$compile", "$rootScope", "$controller", function ($compile, $rootScope, $controller) {
        //  Create a new scope for the modal.
        var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();

        var inputs = {
            $scope: modalScope
        };

        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var modalElement = linkFn(modalScope);
        inputs.$element = modalElement;

        //  Create the controller, explicitly specifying the scope to use.
        var modalController = $controller(controllerName, inputs);

        if (scopeProperties) {
            for (var inputName in scopeProperties) {
                modalScope[inputName] = scopeProperties[inputName];
            }
        }

        template.dropdown({ anchor: anchor });

        def.resolve(template);
    }]);

    return def;
```

}

Then, my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller("testController", ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
  $scope.ClearAllSelection = function ()
  {

  }
}]);
```

Whenever i call the `ClearAllSelection` from my view I can't access the $scp variable. I can access the scope though using `this`.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you call function in view?

Comment: Can you show the code that shows you can't access $scope ? Can you also show how you are using the controller in the template(/directive)?

Comment: In the template I use for example ng-change="ClearAllSelection()"